# Where to nest methods for manipulating ArrayLists

Tags: java, oop, shuffle

I'm currently attempting to put together a basic game engine for games involving playing cards. I've being doing some research and have realised that the approach I'm taking seems to be different to that taken by others posting online with respect to which classes the methods that manipulate decks (or any collection) of cards are contained within. I am seeking some advice on why one way seems to be preferred over another (mine...).

My current setup uses a generic `CardList class` that contains a variety of methods specifically designed to handle the 'deck' of cards, although it could also be used for player hands, etc. It is a general 'pile' of cards, that may or may not be ordered, and may or may not be visible to each player.

As an example, suppose I want a method to allow me to shuffle a deck of cards. My approach has been to include within the `CardList class` a public method `shuffle()` that shuffles the cards within that list. So it would be called as `deck1.shuffle()` from within the game loop.

What I am seeing is that others have set up a shuffling method within the main game loop and providing the deck they want to shuffle as an input. For instance they may instead use `shuffle(deck1)`.

I am currently attempting (real code more complicated, of course):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // main game loop goes here
    CardList deck1 = new CardList();
    deck1.shuffle();
    // more code
}

public class CardList {
    // attributes and other methods

    public void shuffle() {
        // shuffle code
    }
}
```

Whereas the more common approach seems to be along the lines of:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // main game loop goes here
    Game game1 = new Game();
    CardList deck1 = new CardList();
    // more code
    game1.shuffle(deck1); // or alternatively, within a method in the Game class
    // more code
}

public class Game {
    public void shuffle(CardList list) {
        // shuffle code
    }
    // attributes and other methods
}

public class CardList {
    // attributes and methods
}
```

So the question seems to be, should it be an inherent method within the object's own class, or should it be an external method that takes the object to be shuffled as an input?

I am keen to hear advantages/disadvantages to both approaches - I can't see why 2 would be preferred to 1 myself!

Comment: can you please post some link of the approach taken by others posting online?

Answer (score 1):

First, isn't logical to put a `suffle` method in a class named `Game`; you can't "shuffle" a game :)

For me, the best approach to shuffle a `List` is by using the native `Collection` library:

```
ArrayList<Card> cardlist = new ArrayList<>();
cardlist.add("card1");
Collections.shuffle(cardlist);
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-shuffle-java-examples/

For your class `CardList` I suggest to do this:

```
public class CardList {
    // attributes and other methods

    ArrayList<Card> cardlist = new ArrayList<>();

    public CardList shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(cardlist);

        return this;
    }
}
```

By doing so you can use the chain method invocation to shuffle and immediately get back the shuffled list:

```
myCardListObject.shuffle().otherMethod()...
```

Comment: I realise this is an option for shuffling, but that is just an example. It may be that other methods need to be used. For instance, revealing a number of cards, adding a card, drawing a card. The context isn't too important, more the general approach.

Comment: Many thanks - this more resembles my current code, and confirms that at least one other person thinks it is a sensible approach!